# Bulk insert or update with Couchbase Ottoman

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-nodejs-sdk, couchbase-ottoman

Is it possible to do bulk inserts and/or update with Couchbase Ottoman?
I am trying to build a script that imports my data from a MySQL database, and I would rather not import each model one at a time.

Comment: Is there any reason you just don't write up a simple program in C# or Java to do it? Would take less than an hour.

Comment: I am writing the backend server with node and Ottoman has actually a very nice abstraction. I am trying to reduce the number of platform used on my projects, since it gets very hard for new developers to come in, if they have to know more than three or four frameworks/programming languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible to get more context on your models, and how you're loading from mysql?   There is currently no bulk method for saving.  While not ideal, if you're populating models based on a query from mysql, it should be possible within the same scope to iterate through and save them within couchbase.  If you can provide more information, I'd be happy to help.

Thanks

Todd

Comment: Thanks Todd, this is actually how I ended up doing it. I was just hoping there was some kind of bulk operations, which would be more efficient, but since there are none, and this is not something that is going to run frequently I guess it should be good enough.

Comment: have you find any option for bulk insert or update in couchbase by ottoman?